# Hi , I am writing the simple oddeven program in python but getting the error " IndentationError: expected an indented block"

Tags: python-3.x

var1 = input("Enter any number")  if (var1 % 2) == 0: print"even", var1  else: print"odd number", var1

Comment: That is indeed some good identation

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3, use print correct, and secondly your input needs to be converted to an integer.
Example:

```
var1 = int(input("Enter any number"))
if (var1 % 2) == 0:
    print("even", var1)
else: print("odd number", var1)
```

Tabs (or spaces) are important part of Python :) Read all about it!